# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken but CSRF tokens match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I'm sending a POST to my server. In the  tag, I see `<meta name="csrf-token" content="U3QYXIcVmME8WyC1vew+u0XCWRQ1H5X1nAw2LuGpEJ4gYoXRfYS9DH+JW3OFJf0WrFpvJe4TqqjQ9gGlqC8OkQ==">`

When the POST hits the server, I see `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"U3QYXIcVmME8WyC1vew+u0XCWRQ1H5X1nAw2LuGpEJ4gYoXRfYS9DH+JW3OFJf0WrFpvJe4TqqjQ9gGlqC8OkQ=="}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.`

Any idea what might be causing this? I've diffed the tokens and they're identical.

I'm passing requests through a reverse proxy before hitting my rails server, so I was assuming the cookie was getting munged before hitting rails but the parameters show it isn't. Very confused :/